# CodeIgniter email Email helper doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm working on a password reset function oon Codeigniter, I'm a newbie with this framework but I've followed all the instructions here's my controller :

```
$email= $this->input->post('email');

 $this->load->helper('string');
 $rs= random_string('alnum', 12);

 $data = array(
           'password' => md5($rs)
         );

 $this->db->where('email', $email);
 $this->db->update('user', $data);

 //now we will send an email

  $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
  $config['smtp_host'] = 'My SMTP Host';
  $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
  $config['smtp_user'] = '***@gmail.com';
  $config['smtp_pass'] = 'Account Password';

  $this->load->library('email', $config);
  $this->email->initialize($config);
  $this->email->from('info@link-sa.ga');
  $this->email->to($email);

  $this->email->subject('Mot de passe oublier');
  $this->email->message('Votre Nouveau mot de passe est :'.$rs );

  $this->email->send();
```

And here's the debug page:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2keUK5KhVo8MUg3WVJKemZPcEE/edit?usp=drivesdk

I'm sure that all the mail server information are correct, but the email is not sent to the user, I wish you can help me, and thanks to everybody

Comment: `echo $this->email->print_debugger();`

Comment: Maybe try 587 port instead of 465.

Comment: from your debug it seems that your smtp credentials are incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with

```
$config['smtp_port'] = '587';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
```

more info https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13287 and http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/84689/P0/

Comment: Another problem appeared to me:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2keUK5KhVo8bHJtbFJpbS1LN0k/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: It's done, it was because of the account, the account of gmail has a problem, I've changed it and it works with no problem, thanks to every one